# Group by and diffrence timestamps in consecutive rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data frame with a list of periods and timestamps. I want to group by period and sort by timestamp (to make sure the observations are in chronological order within the periods), then difference the corresponding timestamps - to calculate the difference between the current observation and the next

```
period_df = pd.DataFrame({
                'Period': ['Period 1', 'Period 1', 'Period 1', 'Period 1', 'Period 1',
                           'Period 2', 'Period 2', 'Period 2', 'Period 2', 'Period 2'],
                'time': ['1900-01-01 05:01:00', '1900-01-01 05:01:00',
                         '1900-01-01 06:01:00',
                         '1900-01-01 06:01:00', '1900-01-01 06:31:00', '1900-01-01 06:01:00', '1900-01-01 06:01:00',
                         '1900-01-01 06:31:00',
                         '1900-01-01 06:31:00', '1900-01-01 07:31:00']})
```

I can group the data frame by the 'Period' column and then sort the data frame by time and create a new column with the lead time values, and difference the corresponding lead time and time values, to do this.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Can you provide your code and the expected output please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I can group the data frame by the 'Period' column and then sort the data frame by time and create a new column with the lead time values, and difference the corresponding lead time and time values, to do this.

Your solution seems to be optimal, but maybe you can sort the data once instead of in each group:

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])

out = (df.sort_values(['Period', 'time'])
         .assign(diff=lambda x: x.groupby('Period')['time'].diff()))
```

Output:

```
>>> out
     Period                time            diff
0  Period 1 1900-01-01 05:01:00             NaT
1  Period 1 1900-01-01 05:01:00 0 days 00:00:00
2  Period 1 1900-01-01 06:01:00 0 days 01:00:00
3  Period 1 1900-01-01 06:01:00 0 days 00:00:00
4  Period 1 1900-01-01 06:31:00 0 days 00:30:00
5  Period 2 1900-01-01 06:01:00             NaT
6  Period 2 1900-01-01 06:01:00 0 days 00:00:00
7  Period 2 1900-01-01 06:31:00 0 days 00:30:00
8  Period 2 1900-01-01 06:31:00 0 days 00:00:00
9  Period 2 1900-01-01 07:31:00 0 days 01:00:00
```